# Should we lose the zero in the bounties tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

It has been awhile since the filtering functionality was introduced and despite
the positives, this feature also brought an undesirable change.

The bounties tab now has a very prominent zero in blue:

[image]

I have tried to ignore it but my eyes go straight on there whenever I load Stack
Overflow. Despite my best efforts, I cannot get used to it. Does anyone else have this problem?

Would it not be best if we went back to the previous implementation where the
bounties tab was only appearing when there were active bounties?

Or alternatively we could at least get rid of the bold blue zero if there are no active bounties? The bounties tab could still be displayed for design consistency.

Comment: Another suggestion: Why don't we put the bounties on the side tab?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The very intrusive blue zero has now finally been removed from the bounties tab:

[image]

This welcome change appears to have been implemented across all Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further reflection and deliberation in comments, I suggest we display the *Bounties tab* at all time, even when there is actually no active bounty for posts falling under a given tag.

It will help enhance user experience knowing there is in no active bounty rather than confusion that may possibly be induced by its conditional availability.

There should be no concern with screen readers getting it wrong if properly executed; have not test the current and cannot comment on status of screenreader friendliness.

Comment: All past evidence has shown that just hiding something confuses users far more. Actively showing that there are no questions with bounties is a far better user experience than hiding the tab and leaving them to wonder where it went. Sorry, but just hiding it isn't gonna happen.

Comment: @animuson it is not a "far better" user experience sticking a bold blue zero in a neutral color bar. I have no problem with the tab showing but as it stands it is just bad design.

Comment: @animuson I would also be interested in taking a look at the evidence you mention. Is it publicly available?

Comment: @Pearly I'm not against hiding the number, only the tab. We've had countless support questions and "bug" reports in the past of people trying to find that tab only to learn it was "hidden because it was zero" - it does confuse a lot of people. It also completely breaks the experience for users who were already sorted to bounties and then changed the search, and now the tab is hidden so they don't know they're still sorted by something not visible.

Comment: @nyedidikeke Would you hide the spam folder from the user if there was no messages in it? Compeletely agree with animuson here

Comment: @DollarAkshay: I get your point. Thanks for the analogy: it helps set the right context.  